# How to check if table is empty in SAP Adobe Form?

Tags: livecycle, livecycle-designer, adobe-form

I have an Adobe non-interactive form and 2 tables. And also one field type "text" which should be hidden if one of those tables is empty. This code to hide the field is working fine

```
this.history_data.st_text.presence = "hidden";
```

but this is only working in case there is no if-statement around it. Now I want to check if the table `data.history_data.example_table` is empty.

Anybody knows how to do it?